# Current Date Validation using JavaScript in ASP.Net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to validate a date input box to check whether it's a current date/future date/invalid date and I'm using the following code for that but it's not working at all. I tried using a div tag as well as label but it won't just display anything. I picked up this code from stackoverflow itself. Please help.Thank you in advance.

Here is my    **ASPX Code**

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="txt_orange">*</span><span class="LabelClass">Request Created on</span>
                                <br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_req_createdon_new" runat="server" CssClass="form-control dtPick funkystyling" onBlur="CheckForEmpty(this.id,'Select Start Date')" onkeyup="checkDate()" ></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txt_req_createdon_new" CssClass="red" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">`enter code here`
                                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                <%--<asp:Label ID="Valid" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>--%>

                            </div>

                            <div id="Valid" runat="server"></div>
```

Here is the **JavaScript Code**

```
function isFutureDate(idate) {
            var today = new Date().getTime(),
                idate = idate.split("/");

            idate = new Date(idate[2], idate[1] - 1, idate[0]).getTime();
            return (today - idate) < 0 ? true : false;
        }    

        function checkDate() {
            var idate = document.getElementById("txt_req_createdon_new"),
            resultDiv = document.getElementById("Valid"),

            dateReg = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012])[\/]201[4-9]|20[2-9][0-9]/;               

            if (dateReg.test(idate.value)) {
                if (isFutureDate(idate.value)) {
                    resultDiv.innerHTML = "Entered date is a future date";
                    resultDiv.style.color = "red";
                } else {
                    resultDiv.innerHTML = "It's a valid date";
                    resultDiv.style.color = "green";
                }
            } else {
                resultDiv.innerHTML = "Invalid date!";
                resultDiv.style.color = "red";
            }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set ClientIDMode to static.

By default ClientIDMode is Auto, which means, client Id will be generated by concatenating the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control. [See](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example:

```
<asp:Label ID="Valid" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am glad to tell you that your script is just working fine. I tested it and here are the results.

[image]
[image]

Now the issue, as per my thinking is that you might have kept the script on the top section of your page. Meaning it is kept somewhere before the `TextBox` code is declared. Try putting the script at the bottom of your page. After `body` or anywhere you like, but it should be near the ending. That might help.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Working on a 3 tier application so I'm writing the script tag in the first Content Place Holder.

Comment: That means your textbox is possibly in the latter Content Place Holder/s.Try enclosing the function with a `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: I wrote it like this, but it still won't work.



       ` $(document).ready(function isFutureDate(idate) {
            var today = new Date().getTime(),
                idate = idate.split("/");

            idate = new Date(idate[2], idate[1] - 1, idate[0]).getTime();
            return (today - idate) < 0 ? true : false;
        }); `

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what error you are getting ? Would be good if you show it in Inspect Element.